# How to Download Windows Media Device Manager 11 SDK?

Tags: windows-7, msdn, winapi, mtp

I want to compile the [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff801002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the [Windows Media Device Manager 11 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff801840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - but I cannot figure out how to download it. The original download link doesn't work - and in the Windows SDK I cannot find the examples!

EDIT2: I want to access devices via MTP on Windows 7 with an custom application.

Comment: Charly, I added additional things you can try as listed in my comments several days ago. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/c/3/ac367925-39e7-4451-a175-a224f94fbdce/wmformat11sdk.exe

It was buried down in the comments on the SDK documentation.

**EDIT:**

If you're wanting to do MTP on Windows 7, you might want to look at the Windows 7 Portable Device Enabling Kit for MTP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463543.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the Link, but it's only working with WinXP - I'm using Win7. Why don't I find it in the [MSDN Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570309)

Comment: It seems that the "Portable Device Enabling Kit" is aimed to manufacturers (I guess it will be helpful later one - but right now my device is already shown in the Explorer). So I would need the Host side, to access the device by software.

Comment: Download link for wmformat11sdk.exe is no longer working. :-(

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly I looks like Microsoft has rolled that SDK into the full Windows SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The webpage you provided for that SDK states the **Windows Media Device Manager 11 SDK** is a component of a ***Microsoft Kit***.

I discovered via Google search that there are different kits depending on the Windows version your using.

That same first page of hits revealed *[Aaron Stebner's WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/02/13/9420404.aspx)* which provides the Microsoft links you need to download this kit for ***Windows 7***:

[**Microsoft Windows Media Software Development Kit**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18400)

That **112.5 MB Kit** also contains ***documentation***, ***tools***, and ***sample code*** to get you started.

Since **MTP** (**[Media Transport Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)**) is part of that Kit's framework, I'm hoping there's going to be examples provided once you [**download and install the MSI package**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/C/6/6C6B665D-6240-4958-A028-A944B8BD6860/WindowsMediaCenterSDK6.msi) the complete kit, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: hmmm... I ve installed it, and at least the 'windows media device manager SDK examples' (wmdmapp) are not included...

Comment: This webpage titled [**What's Included with the SDK (Windows)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff801839%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) might be useful?

Comment: Something else to try: Now that you have the Kit installed, how about *re-running* the actual **MSI Component** to see if that ***MSI Package*** has option to install just the project files?  Use a program like [**7zip**](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract XP Version of [**wmformat11sdk.exe**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/c/3/ac367925-39e7-4451-a175-a224f94fbdce/wmformat11sdk.exe) and you will get a subfolder with the **WMFormatSDK.msi** package inside of that. Worst case scenario is you can extract that MSI package to access all files... but perhaps there are no Windows 7 projects?

Comment: About the worst case scenario... follow [**this thread**](http://superuser.com/a/307679) to extract the MSI contents which includes the subfolders and therefore appears to be the same as installing the package itself when it doesn't install correctly.